# How to save a Facebook Banner so it is optimized for BOTH mobile and web?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, resolution, compression

I'm trying to add a new banner image to my Facebook page. It's the correct size of 851x315 and I have saved it in both JPEG and PNG, clocking in at 77Kb. The image looks fine on Desktop but when I view it on mobile it appears pixelated.

I know Facebook can be bad for compressing which is why I always make sure they are under 100Kb but this is the first time I've had it show pixelation issues only on mobile, usually the issues would appear on both mobile and desktop.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4uub.jpg)

[Screenshot of Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl4lJ.png)

[Screenshot of Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5XEO.jpg)

What should the settings for exporting be to work for both desktops and mobile?

Comment: 1) I know (or think I know) facebook *always* recompresses uploads; 2) rather than a mobile screenshot, you need to see if you can track down the image asset itself and see what the actual asset specs and quality are. I presume this is an app though, so it may be difficult. The image may be the least-common-denominator size their app supports (e.g. android 320px screen) and is being upsampled (or stretched) for your (probably) high-density screen (1080px etc)

Comment: @Yorik I figure it is being upsampled, it's on my iPhone 6 Plus, but there has got to be some sort of export options or settings that I'm missing since few other Facebook banners look like that on my phone.

Comment: I suspect it might be a different size now to account for pixel density on more advanced smartphones and retina displays. Not sure though.

Comment: @Ryan I would have thought so too but according to their help site that is still the current sizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging on other peoples cover images it seems that the theory of keeping it under 100Kb is best ignored. An image of 1500x500 (Twitters banner size) and under 1Mb seems to work well on desktop and only have minor pixilation on mobile.